# Make mp4 from continuous jpg in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ffmpeg

Client is sending continuous jpg to my server.
The issue is: how to make one mp4 file from all these jpg files?

I can save them all and use ffmpeg with “filename%3d.jpg”, when client finish sending files.

But is there any way to make it real-time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can turn it into an mjpeg stream and mux it into an mp4 using any one of the many open source libraries that can do this. Or you can choose to reencode to a more temporal efficient codec such as h.264 to save final file size and bandwidth.

But either way, and MP4 is not usable until the last frame is written, so I'm not sure what the actually gain is from this exercise exercise.

Comment: Thank you! How can I turn it to mpeg stream?

Comment: Sorry, That should have said mjpeg stream.